# How do you manage divergent schemas on different deployments in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a situation where my rails app (R) is used to view and modify a database that is managed by another (non-ruby) application (A). (A) is the main app of the business and (R) is just support for administrators. Hence (R) just uses the schema provided, with no migrations to setup/modify the database (which is handled by (A)).

The problem I have is that (A) has several different deployments, to which (R) needs to also be deployed. However, the schema for the databases are different for each deployment (as (A) is upgraded at different times, and also moves in different directions). The ideal situation is that all deployments can be updated to the lastest release, and have a consistent database structure for (A) and (R) - but this is not realistically possible.

I'm currently managing these (R) releases with different branches, and cherry-picking changes one by one, but this is becoming unwieldy. Especially because there are 7 branches at the moment, with this number growing.

Is there a better way? Would it help to decouple the database layer with the web app on the rails side? How would that work?

Comment: When you write data with R, does A need to see it?

Comment: @ryan1234 Yes. (R) basically administers (A). (A) is just for everyday consumers.

Comment: Gah. I was going to suggest replicating the data for R to work on its own and that way the schemas can diverge over time. But if R is writing data that A needs, that obviously won't work. You mentioned decoupling the database layer from the application. Do you have database calls (SQL statements for example) in the Ruby code?

Comment: There aren't direct sql statements. Just using ActiveRecord to map over the database mainly.

Comment: I wish I had a solution, but I can't think of anything. Ha. If the applications are so tightly coupled (sharing a schema that has many branches), then I don't know how to make life easier on you. If I were you I would try to make as clear of a division as I could between the applications. I would want my R app to have it's own database/schema/data and then create a very clear interface to A. The less they share, the better. But if data is shared heavily - and they are so dependent on each other, I think you'll always be subject to their release behavior.